# How to replace flatCollect in Squeak 4.5?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

I wanted to port a program from Squeak 4.4 to Squeak 4.5 but get the error message: `OrderedCollection(Object)>>doesNotUnderstand:#flatCollect:`.

`flatCollect` does not seem to be available anymore in Squeak 4.5. Does anybody know a good replacement for it?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply replace all occurrences of `flatCollect:` with `gather:`.
It has basically the same functionality.

Comment: Note that #flatCollect: did not exist in Squeak 4.4 either. This is a message that comes from the Pharo fork.